# NoClassDefFoundError Exception android joda time

Tags: java, android, jodatime

I am building an application and using Joda Time in it instead java built in Date/Time classes. but i am facing a problem that when i compile the app using 
**Android API 22** it runs fine, but when i compile it with **android API 23** it throws **NoClassDefFoundError** exception.
My **build.gradle**  is following

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
    applicationId 'com.my.app'
    minSdkVersion 11
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 6
    versionName '5.0.1'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
        //runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets', 'src/main/assets/downloadMusicMishari', 'src/main/assets/downloadmusicSaad']
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        incremental true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    //compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0'
    compile project(':facebook')
    compile project(':library')
    compile files('libs/PayPalAndroidSDK-2.9.10.jar')
    compile files('libs/picasso-2.5.2.jar')
    compile project(':justifiedTextViewmaster')
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

and here is the screen shot of error.
[image]

Comment: u have missed some jars to add into classpath, add those classess into classpath..

Comment: @NaveenShriyan i did not quite get you?

Comment: right click on the libraries that u have added and there is option called add to class path click on that, M not sure it will work or not but try once, And this exception is bec Those classes are available at the compile time but a the run time JVM not able to find those classes so throwing this exception.

Comment: @NaveenShriyan thanks for commenting. i will let you know if it helps

Comment: sure let me know if it helps..

Answer (score 3):

**NoClassDefFoundError**

> Thrown if the Java Virtual Machine or a ClassLoader instance tries to
>   load in the definition of a class (as part of a normal method call or
>   as part of creating a new instance using the new expression) and no
>   definition of the class could be found.

Please check **[Joda-Time library with Android specialization](https://github.com/dlew/joda-time-android)**

Try with:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'net.danlew:android.joda:2.9.2' // For API Level 23 or Above
}
```

Then ***Clean-Rebuild*** Your IDE

**Edit**

make sure you initialize `JodaTimeAndroid.init(this);`

> Once that's done, you must initialize the library before using it by
>   calling JodaTimeAndroid.init(). I suggest putting this code in
>   Application.onCreate():

```
public class YourApplicationClass extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        JodaTimeAndroid.init(this);
    }
}
```

**Final Edit**

```
Removed Joda plugin
```

Comment: thanks for suggesting this. i am trying it and will let you know if it works

Comment: @Tahir did you call this in your `Application`

Comment: btw my app takes a lot of time in building like more than 10 minutes, before i migrated to API 23 it always build with in a minute. what do you think where is the problem?

Comment: which version you are using ? https://dzone.com/articles/how-speed-your-gradle-build-90

Comment: No not yet, I'm finding a way where i dont need to use Joda plugin

Comment: i have fixed my Problem but i have removed Joda plugin. thanks for your assistance

Answer (score 2):

**NoClassDefFoundError**

> is thrown if the Java Virtual Machine or a ClassLoader instance tries
>   to load in the definition of a class (as part of a normal method call
>   or as part of creating a new instance using the new expression) and no
>   definition of the class could be found.
>
> The searched-for class definition existed when the currently executing
>   class was compiled, but the definition can no longer be found.

[[See This]](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError.html)

So consider using a JODA library that is specifically designed for Android. You may ask why use this library instead of the other. There is one particular problem with the other. ie due to its usage of `ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream()`, it greatly inflates its memory footprint on apps. (For more details, see [this blog post](http://blog.danlew.net/2013/08/20/joda_time_s_memory_issue_in_android/).) This library avoids the problem for Android.

Also this library has extra utilities designed for Android. For example, see [DateUtils](https://github.com/dlew/joda-time-android/blob/master/library/src/main/java/net/danlew/android/joda/DateUtils.java), a port of Android's [DateUtils.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html)

Try changing `compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.3'`

to: `compile 'net.danlew:android.joda:2.9.1'`

This works well. And I am using this in an app with SDK 23!

**EDIT 1**

If it's ISO8601 format, then you can parse it even without using Joda. This way:

```
try {
        DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
        Date result = format.parse("2015-05-19T04:00:00.000Z");
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(result);
        int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        output = day+" "+month+" "+year;
        Log.w("THE DATE IS:",""+output);
    }
    catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
```

Comment: thanks for you advice. i am trying it and will let you know if it helps

Comment: sadly it did not worked app crashes with the same exception

Comment: You need to initialize Joda before using it? did you do that?

Comment: Yes i am trying it now.

Comment: btw my app takes a lot of time in building like more than 10 minutes, before i migrated to API 23 it always build with in a minute.

Comment: Even I experienced that while building the project! No solution as of now!

Comment: It is basically because JODA is a very big library, takes time to initiate!

Comment: What are you trying to convert? Is it an ISO date format?

Comment: now it is throwing exception at line number v where i initialize JodaTimeAndroid.init(this);

Comment: i have fixed my Problem by removing Joda plugin. thanks for your guidance