# Google play-services-base breaks joda time in debug build

Tags: java, android, google-play-services

We're encountering a really frustrating problem with our app. While trying to add the google play location service, we're getting a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.joda.time.chrono.ISOChronology`. This is only happening on our debug build.  We've narrowed it down to the line

`compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.8.0"`

in our `build.gradle`.  Inlcuding this line will cause this error regardless of whether the location services are used or not.

Our dependencies in our application level `build.gradle` are the following
```
dependencies {
    compile project(':dependencies:volley')

```
compile project(':modules:app-config')
compile project(':modules:reeldatabase')
compile project(':modules:sync')

compile project(':modules:greeting')
compile project(':modules:login')
compile project(':modules:viewshifts')
compile project(':modules:workshift')

// Google Support Libraries
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ANDROID_SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VER}"
compile "com.android.support:support-v4:${rootProject.ANDROID_SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VER}"
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:${rootProject.FIREBASE_VER}"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.8.0"

// Mock Web Server
debugCompile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:mockwebserver:3.2.0'
// Developer Tools
debugCompile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.3.1'

// Journey Tests
androidTestCompile "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:$rootProject.ESPRESSO_VER"
androidTestCompile ("com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:$rootProject.ESPRESSO_VER") {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks

Comment: You may want to check the solution in the related [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35865127/5995040) by changing the dependency to `'net.danlew:android.joda:2.9.2'` or if it's ISO8601 format, then you can parse it even without using Joda. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response; we ended up figuring out what it was as answered below.

Answer (score 0):

It ended up that this was because the addition of the location services caused us to exceed the 64k method limit, and was only occurring in the debug build because we had proguard removing unused methods in our release build.